# Change "line" autoref tag in algorithm2e using spanish language option

Tags: hyperref, babel, algorithm2e

I'm using Latex and the package algorithm2e to write algorithms down.

I reference a line with `\autoref` and the package hyperref generates "línea 3". I'd like to change the word "línea" to other word such as "Paso" or "Línea" (capital letter). How can I do so?

I've used
`\addto\extrasspanish{\def\algorithmautorefname{Algoritmo}}` to rename the word "algoritmo" as the package documentation says, but homologously `\addto\extrasspanish{\def\lineautorefname{Paso}}` is not working

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[spanish, ruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\def\algorithmautorefname{Algoritmo}
\def\lineautorefname{Paso}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \DontPrintSemicolon

        Hacer algo \label{line:3} \;

        Volver al \autoref{line:3} \;

        \caption{My caption here!}
        \label{mylabel}
    \end{algorithm}

    Reference to the \autoref{mylabel} here.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word for "line"  is stored in `\algorithmcflinename`. You can change it as shown in the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish, ruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algoritmo}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcflinename}{Paso}
\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \DontPrintSemicolon

        Hacer algo \label{line:3} \;

        Volver al \autoref{line:3} \;

        \caption{My caption here!}
        \label{mylabel}
    \end{algorithm}

    Reference to the \autoref{mylabel} here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!!!